# Count distinct occurrences as a subsequence

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am going through "Count distinct occurrences as a subsequence problem" from geeksforgeeks. I wish to understand the "else" case. In the case when the last character matches why is the result without last character from S + without last two characters from S and T?

```
Input  : S = banana, T = ban
Output : 3
T appears in S as below three subsequences.
[ban], [ba  n], [b   an]

// Returns count of subsequences of S that match T 
// m is length of T and n is length of S
subsequenceCount(S, T, n, m)
```

// An empty string is subsequence of all.
   1) If length of T is 0, return 1.

// Else no string can be a sequence of empty S.
   2) Else if S is empty, return 0.

3) Else if last characters of S and T don't match,
      remove last character of S and recur for remaining
        return subsequenceCount(S, T, n-1, m)

4) Else (Last characters match), the result is sum
      of two counts.

```
    // Remove last character of S and recur.
    a) subsequenceCount(S, T, n-1, m) + 

    // Remove last characters of S and T, and recur.
    b) subsequenceCount(S, T, n-1, m-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case where `S="banan"`, and `T="ban"`. The last characters match, so any occurrence of `T` in a subsequence of `S` must either:

- Not include the last character of `S`. This reduces to the subproblem `S="bana"`, `T="ban"`, which has 1 occurrence: "**ban**a".
- Include the last character of `S`. This reduces to the subproblem `S="bana"`, `T="ba"`. Here there are 2 occurrences: "**ba**na" and "**b**an**a**". If we go back to the main problem, the corresponding occurrences are "**ba**na**n**" and "**b**an**an**".

The total count of occurrences is the sum of both subproblems.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a simpler solution
S = "banana"
T = "ban"

```
int solve(int i, int j, string &S, string &T){
 if(j>=T.size())
    return 1;
 else if(i>=A.size() && j<T.size())
    return 0;
 int sum = 0;

 sum = solve(i+1, j, S, T);

 if(S[i] == T[j]){
   sum += solve(i+1, j+1, S, T);
 }
 return sum;
}
```

In this solution, `i` represents an index of S string, and `j` represents an index of T string. At any state `(i, j)`, we have two possible scenarios, either the characters represented at the given indices of both the strings match or don't match.

1. If the chars match or don't match, we have to move to next the char of S string, because the string T can be found in next subpart of S.
2. If the chars match, then move to next characters of each string.
3. Lastly, take the sum of both possible recursive relation and return it.

Comment: can you please add memoized solution to this recursive code?